# Organizing functions within a class

Tags: c++, oop

I want to put all of a classes functions into a "subdomain" (what is the right term for this?), such as the `functions` part of `myClass.functions.function1();`

So how should one rewrite this for that purpose?

```
    class MYCLASS {
      private:
        int data;
      public:
        int function1();
        int function2();
        int function3();
    };
```

So that the class could then be used:

```
    MYCLASS myClass;
    myClass.functions.function1();
```

rather than using just `myClass.function1();`.

Comment: Unless the function require some shared state held by the class, you should group them in a namespace.

Comment: They do require shared data. Also, I thought you couldn't have a class with more than one namespaces?

Comment: @ConfusedStack: You can't have a class with _any_ nested namespace.

Comment: Don't make a god class. Design your classes around specific, small, focused responsibilities.

Comment: I don't know what a class with more than one namespace actually means, but what I meant was that you wouldn't have any classes. But if you need the shared state that changes things.

Answer (score 3):

You can make these *free functions* in some descriptive namespace, or you can emplace them inside a nested class. However, both of these imply access to members only through the original class's interface, meaning you will still need some public functions inside the class itself.

Otherwise, it's already clear that these are functions, so I would simply *not do this*. If you want to because you have loads and loads of functions, then you have too many functions, and your class almost certainly does too many things.

Answer (score 0):

Depending our your design (which needs to be object-oriented but not necessarily) you can define a new namespace or an struct or a class which is called nested classes!

for example:

```
class A {
public:
  int a;

  class B {
  public:
    void do_something();

  } bObject;

};
```